# Why custom favicon for Salesforce-powered website not showing consistently in Google search results

Tags: salesforce, favicon

When I search Google for "success qualys", I see a custom favicon.

[image]

But, when I do the same in incognito mode, I see the Salesforce favicon. Why?

[image]